# npm: npm ERR! Failed at the node-pty@0.6.10 install script. When installing Node OS and node-gyp

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to create a Node OS distrobution, after installing its command line dependencies, running "npm install" results in the following error.

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/nodejs/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/vinny/NodeOS/node_modules/node-pty
gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-pty@0.6.10 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-pty@0.6.10 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-02-26T23_32_45_386Z-debug.log
```

As you can tell, I am running WSL, and I have VcXsrv installed and working properly, so don't worry about that.

But how do I sucessfully install node-gyp?
Thanks in advance!